# Canvas scaler with particles system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using the **Canvas Scaler** component and my particles system not scaling correctly.

I'm using the next code to change shape scale but that not working always. For example 900x600 (3:2). Do you have any variants?

```cs
particlesShape.scale *= canvasObj.sizeDelta.x / designWidth;
```

Comment: this may help.  https://gist.github.com/TobiTobascoNollero/927eb9dc812f86c88421dc5747d86688

Comment: @siusiulala thanks for your request, but I saw the current solution and it not works. I've resolved the problem by Unity properties of the scaling mode. Just need to select scaling mode by hierarchy.